# Value not binding in XAML Page in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a text that is changing dynamically and needs to be updated in user interface, but it is not binding.

Here is the view model:

```cs
internal class PowerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Power { get; set; }
    
    public PowerViewModel()
    {  
        MessagingCenter.Instance.Subscribe<App, string>(this, "power_topic", OnPowerChanged);
    }
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    private void OnPowerChanged(App app, string power)
    {
        Power = power;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Power)));
    }
}
```

the method `OnPowerChanged()` is being triggered and `Power` is taking a value.

The view code and binding is this:

```cs
namespace IotApp.Views
{
    public partial class ItemDetailPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ItemDetailPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new PowerViewModel();
            BindingContext = new ItemDetailViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the xaml code:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:IotApp.ViewModels" x:DataType="viewmodels:PowerViewModel"
             x:Class="IotApp.Views.ItemDetailPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:PowerViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <ContentPage.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
            <GradientStop Color="#faeee2" Offset="0.1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#a0bec6" Offset="0.5"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </ContentPage.Background>
        
    <Shell.TitleView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="Home" FontSize="16"/>
            <Image Source="logo_white" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </Shell.TitleView>
    
    <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15" VerticalOptions="Start">
    
        <Label Text="{Binding Power}"  FontSize="18" TextColor="#1c2d57" />
    
    </StackLayout>
    
</ContentPage>
```

It should show the value of `Power`, but is empty all the time, I just can't figure out why.
Please, help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You're setting the `BindingContext` twice, the second assignment overwrites the first one: `BindingContext = new PowerViewModel(); BindingContext = new ItemDetailViewModel();`. Is that a typo/copy paste error, or is that intentional?

Comment: Actually, **three** times because it is also set in the XAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

The problem is that you're setting the `BindingContext` multiple times.

You set it twice here:

```cs
namespace IotApp.Views
{
    public partial class ItemDetailPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ItemDetailPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new PowerViewModel();
            BindingContext = new ItemDetailViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

And a third time here:

```xml
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodels:PowerViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

The second assignment in the code-behind takes precedence, so you're effectively trying to bind to the wrong ViewModel.

## Solution

Remove the assignment of the `BindingContext` in the XAML and also remove the second assignment in the code behind, so that the code looks like this:

```cs
namespace IotApp.Views
{
    public partial class ItemDetailPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ItemDetailPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new PowerViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i didn't notice that as a problem, this solved my issue. Thanks!